# Return value of App must be an instance Laravel error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-6, php-carbon

i have File Uploader that i want to show **Expired** instead of download link when
its expiration date **greater than or equals** today's date

its my model:

```
class Panelfile extends Model
{

protected $guarded = [];

public function
getLinkAttribute()
{
    return
    $this->isExpired() ? null :
    $this->file;
}

public function
isExpired() : boolean
{
   return Carbon::now()->gte($this->expiration);
}

protected $appends = ["link"];

protected $casts = [
    'expiration' =>
    'datatime:Y-m-d H:i:s',
];
}
```

and its my view:

```
@foreach($filepanels as $filepanel)
            
            <div class="widget-download-file d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center mr-3">
                    <div class="download-file-icon mr-3" style="background-color: {{$filepanel->color}};">

                        <img src="{{$filepanel->png}}" alt="">

                    </div>
                    <div class="user-text-table">
                        <h6 class="d-inline-block font-15 mb-0">{{$filepanel->title}}</h6>
                        <p class="mb-0">{{$filepanel->description}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

               @if ($filepanel->link === null)
                <p>Expired</p>
@else
    <a href="{{$filepanel->file}}" class="download-link badge badge-primary badge-pill">دانلود</a>
                @endif

            </div>
                @endforeach
```

and its my error:

```
Return value of App\Panelfile::isExpired() must be an instance of phpDocumentor\Reflection\Types\Boolean, bool returned (View: C:\wamp64\www\site\resources\views\back\filesview\view.blade.php)
```

how can i solve that?

Comment: Can you post the model code along with use statment included(imported classes and traits).

Comment: namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use phpDocumentor\Reflection\Types\Boolean;

Comment: can you try removing the `use phpDocumentor\Reflection\Types\Boolean`  and change `public function isExpired() : boolean` to `public function isExpired(): bool`

Comment: you are amazing bro that's worked!thanks

Comment: its simple you need to understand the error msg properly. And while using return types make sure that you are writing the test case or use php interface.